# Netbeans 11 not detecting dependencies for JavaFX application with JDK 12

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, java-12

I'm running Netbeans 11 with JDK 12.  I'm trying to create a JavaFX project - following all the steps in the openjfx documentation here:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Specifically: JavaFX and Netbeans - Non-modular with maven

I got the project setup fine and it can run and display whatever components I add to it via SceneBuilder.  However, if I add any other dependencies, I can't import anything from those dependencies.  I can drill down within the added jar in the dependencies list and see the classes defined that I'm trying to add, but the only options I have when trying to fix imports is to create a class for whatever I'm trying to use.  Though everything works fine for javafx-controls and javafx-fxml.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you add a dependency to your pom, if you can see it listed under the `Dependencies` folder, it should be available to use from the editor in any of your classes. Check that you don't have defined `module-info.java`, as that will make your project modular, and it will require that your dependency will be included in it.

Comment: module-info.java was the problem.  Removed that and imports started working.  Thanks.